# VBA to add the new file names to by spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone help? (new to VBA)

I am trying to create a VBA that looks at my current list of file names in a spreadsheet and finds filenames that are not in my list and populates the spreadsheet with the new filenames.

So for example:

I have a list of file names in column “I” I need my VBA to compare this list to my file location in this case “Z:\CLIENTNAME\Waiting\Non-Priority” and add in new filenames. But the VBA cannot delete/ overwrite what is already there it must only add new values on the next available line.  If it can be done the VBA should also not include the document type e.g. .docx (not essential as I can use a formula to get rid of this). I also need the VBA to run even when the workbook is closed (not sure how this is done).

The code I have been using is below, but the problems I am facing with this are:

- Only adding the file names to column A and I cannot seem to change it
- Add document type
- The code below replaces the existing values and does not compare the current values to the folder
- Does not run when workbook is closed

VBA CODE:

```
Sub GetFileNames()
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim splitFile As Variant

   'specify directory to use - must end in "\"
   sPath = "Z:\NAME\Waiting\Non_Priority\"

   iRow = 1
   sFile = Dir(sPath)
    Do While sFile <> ""
        iRow = iRow + 1
        splitFile = Split(sFile, "-")
        For iCol = 0 To UBound(splitFile)
            Sheet1.Cells(iRow, iCol + 1) = splitFile(iCol)
       Next iCol
       sFile = Dir     ' Get next filename
  Loop
End Sub
```

Thank you!!

Comment: VBA cannot run when the workbook is closed, since the VBA is in the workbook. For that you might want to look at VBScript, which works like a standalone program; but is programmed in VBA-Like code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you cannot run VBA when the file is closed, but if your file is open and you run the code below, it will give you your expected results:

```
Sub GetFileNames()
Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required

sPath = "Z:\NAME\Waiting\Non_Priority\"
'specify directory to use - must end in "\"

sFile = Dir(sPath)
Do While sFile <> ""
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row on Column I
    Filename = Left(sFile, InStrRev(sFile, ".") - 1) 'remove extension from file
    Set FoundFile = ws.Range("I1:I" & LastRow).Find(What:=Filename, Lookat:=xlWhole) 'search for existing filename
    If FoundFile Is Nothing Then ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, "I") = Filename 'if not found then add it
    sFile = Dir     ' Get next filename
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: if i wanted to include the date the file was last saved and last saved by which user how would i include this please?